# $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V_{ab} = \langle (1,2,3,1), (1,3,2,1), (2,3,a,b) \rangle$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. For which $a,b$ there exists such subspaces $W, Z \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ that 
>   $$\mathbb{R}^4 = V_{ab} \oplus W = W \oplus Z = V_{ab} \oplus Z$$
>   Show an example of such $W,Z$

We easily show that the set $\lbrace (1,2,3,1), (1,3,2,1), (2,3,a,b) \rbrace$ is linearly dependent iff $a = 7 \land b = 2$. But $\mathbb{R}^4 = V_{ab} \oplus W $ means that $V_{ab} \cap W = \lbrace (0,0,0,0) \rbrace$. So $(1,2,3,1) \notin W$. Analogically $(1,2,3,1) \notin Z$. Hence $(1,2,3,1) \notin W + Z$ but $(1,2,3,1) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ so there are no such subspaces $W,Z$.

Which stays in contradiction with how the task is formulated. (*show an example*)

What am I missing?

Comment: From $v\notin W$ and $v\notin Z$, it does *not* follow that $v\notin W+Z$.

Comment: Yep, once you realize it the exercise is pretty easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Looking at the dimensions, you notice that $V_{ab}$ must be $2$-dimensional in order to have such subspaces $W$ and $Z$. When is $V_{ab}$ $2$-dimensional?

Answer (score 1):

Just because $(1,2,3,1)$ is neither in $Z$ nor in $W$, doesn't mean that it is not in $Z+W$. In fact, all you need to do it is to pick $Z$ and $W$ random enough two-dimensional subspaces so that they have trivial intersection with $V_{ab}$ and each other.

I assume that you know why it is impossible to find $Z$ and $W$ as needed if dimension of $V_{ab}$ is three.